# An error occurred while listing Android targets when installing cordova 3.5.0 on Windows 7

Tags: android, git, cordova, ant

with the help of the phonegap docs( [http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0//guide_cli_index.md.html](http://cordova3.5.0)), i installed node.js, git client and cordova 3.5.0 successfully.
And also i am able to install windows8 and wp8.
But when installing android, i am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\rajkiranb\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:12
6
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.
js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node
_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\
cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: C:\Users\rajkiranb\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Com
mand failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\rajkiranb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

In Computer -> C -> Environment variables..
In user variables and system variables, i added ANT.

ANT_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt

But no luck.

Please help me out.

Comment: Make sure java is installed and the path is added to environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this directly to your path varible

> C:\Users\rajkiranb\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools‌​;C:\Users\rajkiranb\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools

See the second one is `tools` not `build-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have `ANDROID_HOME` system variable set to android sdk location

Comment: I am having ANDROID_HOME= C:\Users\rajkiranb\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\rajkiranb\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools

Comment: That is wrong. Your `ANDROID_HOME` should be `C:\Users\rajkiranb\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk`

Comment: Do you have `ANDROID_HOME\tools` and `ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools` in your `PATH` variable?

Comment: Yes, this is my path variable PATH = C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin;C:\Users\rajkiranb\AppData\Roaming\npm;ANDROID_HOME\tools; ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools

Comment: I am trying all the process through command line but couldn't install android.

Comment: when i run **android** through command line. I'm getting the result as: **'android' is not recognized as an internal or external comand,
operable program or batch file.**